# RECon 2012 and before

Tags: conference

Anyone knows where can I get materials/presentations/trainings from RECon 2012 and before? Is there any place where I could buy it or download it, if it's free - I doubt it, but who knows?

Comment: There are various videos online, but these appear to be presentations, not training material. Just google recon 2012 video for them.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the slides of 2012 [here](http://recon.cx/2012/schedule/index.en.html) in the schedule... the other material can be found [here](http://recon.cx/2012/archive.html)

Have a nice day ;-)